# Dealing with unordered elements?

Tags: haskell, xml-parsing, hxt

I have just started using HXT for parsing some XML documents and am wondering about how to deal with element ordering.

#### Unordered pairs

Consider the following two XML snippets with equivalent data.

```xml
<!-- Version 1 -->
<logistics>
    <deliveryDate>2015-02-24T14:35:00Z</deliveryDate>
    <deliveryAddress>Street Name 12, 93483 City, Country</deliveryAddress>
</logistics>

<!-- Version 2 -->
<logistics>
    <deliveryAddress>Street Name 12, 93483 City, Country</deliveryAddress>
    <deliveryDate>2015-02-24T14:35:00Z</deliveryDate>
</logistics>
```

In order to support both orderings of `deliveryDate` and `deliverAddress` I had to replace XHT's [`xpPair`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-8.3.1/docs/Text-XML-HXT-Arrow-Pickle.html#v%3AxpPair) function with my own `xpUnorderedPair` function:

```hs
xpUnorderedPair :: PU a -> PU b -> PU (a,b)
xpUnorderedPair pa pb = xpAlt (const 0) ps
    where ps = [ xpPair pa pb
               , xpWrap (swap,undefined) $ xpPair pb pa ],
```

which allows me to write the following pickler function:

```hs
xpLogisticsRequirements :: PU LogisticsRequirements
xpLogisticsRequirements = xpElem "logistics" $
                          xpWrap (uncurry LogisticsRequirements,\r -> (deliveryDate r,deliveryAddr r)) $
                          xpUnorderedPair (xpElem "deliveryDate" xpickle)
                                          (xpElem "deliveryAddress" xpText)
```

where `LogisticsRequirements` has type `UTCTime -> String -> LogisticsRequirement`.

#### Unordered triples

Now I can do the same with [`xpTriple`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-8.3.1/docs/Text-XML-HXT-Arrow-Pickle.html#v%3AxpTriple), creating my `xpUnorderedTriple`:

```hs
xpUnorderedTriple :: PU a -> PU b -> PU c -> PU (a,b,c)
xpUnorderedTriple a' b' c' = xpAlt (const 0) ps
    where ps = [ xpWrap (\(a,b,c) -> (a,b,c),undefined) $ xpTriple a' b' c'
               , xpWrap (\(a,c,b) -> (a,b,c),undefined) $ xpTriple a' c' b'
               , xpWrap (\(b,c,a) -> (a,b,c),undefined) $ xpTriple b' c' a'
               , xpWrap (\(b,a,c) -> (a,b,c),undefined) $ xpTriple b' a' c'
               , xpWrap (\(c,a,b) -> (a,b,c),undefined) $ xpTriple c' a' b'
               , xpWrap (\(c,b,a) -> (a,b,c),undefined) $ xpTriple c' b' a' ]
```

and I can keep creating these increasingly big functions (xpUnordered5 will have 120 permutations), but this does not seem right. For the fixed numbers (i.e. pair, triple, t4, t5, etc) I guess I could use Template Haskell to create the functions, but what happens when I want to parse a **list** of different elements.

#### Unordered lists

Considering XML inputs such as this:

```xml
<myList>
    <name>MyList1</name>
    <elemA>...</elemA>
    <elemA>...</elemA>
    <elemB>...</elemB>
    <elemA>...</elemA>
    <elemB>...</elemB>
    <elemC>...</elemC>
    <elemB>...</elemB>
</myList>,
```

how would I go about turning them into

```hs
data MyList = MyList { name   :: String
                     , elemsA :: [ElemA]
                     , elemsB :: [ElemB]
                     , elemsC :: [ElemC] },
```

considering I had the required pickle functions,

```hs
instance XmlPicker ElemA where
    xpickle = xpElemA
instance XmlPicker ElemB where
    xpickle = xpElemB
instance XmlPicker ElemC where
    xpickle = xpElemC
```

I guess an option might be sorting the list of elements and then applying the sequential picklers,

```hs
xpYogurt :: PU MyList
xpYogurt = xpElem "myList" $
         xpWrap (uncurry4 MyList,\l -> (name   l
                                       ,elemsA l
                                       ,elemsB l
                                       ,elemsC l)) $
            xp4Tuple (xpElem "name" xpPrim)
                     (xpList xpElemA)
                     (xpList xpElemB)
                     (xpList xpElemC)
```

but that does not seem very elegant and requires additional sorting logic!

#### First approach:

As proposed by viorior one can define a datatype:

```
data Elem = ElemA ElemA
          | ElemB ElemB
          | ElemC ElemC
```

and then convert the unpickled elements into their respective types, but the problem with that approach is that whilst one can then parse the above list it does not permit unpickling the following slightly modified XML (note the new position of the `<name>` element):

```xml
<myList>
    <elemA>...</elemA>
    <elemA>...</elemA>
    <name>MyList1</name>
    <elemB>...</elemB>
    <elemA>...</elemA>
    <elemB>...</elemB>
    <elemC>...</elemC>
    <elemB>...</elemB>
</myList>,
```

Comment: You could try to create new data `data AllElems = ElemA ElemA | ElemB ElemB | ElemC ElemC ...` and parse into 1 list, then filter it

Comment: Hi Viorior, that approach will let me unpickle an list of mixed `elemA`, `elemB` and `elemC` elements, but it will still require that the name element be either before or after all of those elements, I have updated the example to better show the problem.

Comment: @o1iver Would something [like this](https://gist.github.com/bheklilr/56228d7fd12dd01a5ed5) work?  It's based on the idea that you can get a list of all those elements and then fold over them, but surely you can do something similar using `foldM` or some other appropriate kind of fold.

Comment: Hi bheklilr, that works in terms of parsing that list, but it will simply ignore unknown elements (line 20 of your gist), meaning that the user will not be notified of the superflous list element.

Comment: @o1iver then why not use Either with an appropriate error type and use `foldM` instead? The core idea is the same, you're just adding error handling and using a monadic fold

Comment: @o1iver Check that gist again, I've modified it to use `foldM`.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @bheklilr I understand that approach, but it still has the disadvantage of not running within HXT's parser, meaning that you have to, all of a sudden, deal with your own errors, whereas until now HXT would take care of error handling, etc. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

So far no suitable answers to the actual problem have been provided so here is an alternative (and obvious) XML representation approach that seems more elegant anyway:

```
<myList>
    <name>MyList1</name>
    <elements>
        <elemA>...</elemA>
        <elemA>...</elemA>
        <elemB>...</elemB>
        <elemA>...</elemA>
        <elemB>...</elemB>
        <elemC>...</elemC>
        <elemB>...</elemB>
    </elements>
</myList>.
```